# Why 32 bit Android app can run on 64-bit devices?

Tags: android, react-native

I have an app that was running on React Native 0.53, so if I understand it correctly, it's a 32 bit app and it is running perfectly fine on any latest device which is with 64 bit.

Hence the question, what is different now? Why do my app have to be 64-bit if it was 32-bit app yet running fine on 64-bit device?

Comment: Its a [Google Play Store requirement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html) and [asking why app stores do/require certain things is off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang: I understand it's a PlayStore requirement but I'm asking from technical point of view so I don't think it's off-topic

Comment: They stated their explanation. Another other would be speculation.

Comment: the 64 bit requirement only affects the NDK-related apps (apps that use native libraries/native code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (almost) always run 32bit apps/programms on 64bit CPUs, but not the other way around.

Lately, android devices are getting more and more RAM, the problem is with a 32bit app you can only access 4GB of RAM. In addition you can perform much more calculations on a 64bit CPU than on a 32bit CPU.

I think you need to support 64bit architectures to be more future-proof.

The android team says:

> Starting August 1, 2019, your apps published on Google Play will need
>   to support 64-bit architectures. 64-bit CPUs deliver faster, richer
>   experiences for your users. Adding a 64-bit version of your app
>   provides performance improvements, makes way for future innovation,
>   and sets you up for devices with 64-bit-only hardware.

Source: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: Thank you very much on the explanation, I get a better picture now

Comment: 32-bit apps usually run faster than the same code compiled for 64-bit instructions/pointers.  Fact is, there are zero *mobile* apps out there today that don't fit into a flat 32-bit memory model.   If you think about it, an array of 32-bit integers (or pointers) consume half of the memory than an array of 64-bit ints/pointers.   The upper half of these values is always wasted.   In fact, even on desktops, very few apps require 64-bits.  E.g. all MS Office apps are still 32-bit apps.   A 64-bit OS let's you run a bunch of 32-bit apps.  If you're working with video or large models, however ...

Answer (score 0):

32-bit apps are no more supported on 64-bit CPUs.

> ```
> [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
> Error: Failed to install APK again.
> Error launching application on sdk gphone64 arm64.
> ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).